# SFML doesn't work with CLion on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, linker, sfml, clion

I want to run the following simple C++ SFML application in CLion but when I try to do it, I always get the error message [Test2.exe has stopped working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYnPs.png).

main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}

return 0;
}
```

This might be a problem with CMake, but I don't get any error message from CLion, so I think SFML is found properly.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(Test2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(Test2 main.cpp)

set(SFML_ROOT "C:/Program Files/SFML-2.4.2")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_modules")
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED graphics network audio window system)

if(SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
endif()
```

My SFML is located in C:/Program Files/SFML-2.4.2, and I use the latest version (2.4.2) for MinGW. I have the following MinGW version:
[MingGW configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLtp0.png). My operating system is Windows 8.1 Enterprise.
Separately both CLion and SFML (with Code::Blocks) can work perfectly.

Is there anything I forgot to add to CMakeLists.txt or should I modify some settings in CLion to get SFML to work?

Comment: Did you compile SFML yourself? Otherwise there might be a version mismatch. You can also try to load your executable using [Dependency Walker](https://dependencywalker.com/) to see which DLLs are loaded (because it might pick up wrong versions somewhere based on your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you @Mario, using the program you mentioned, I was able to find out what the problem was and solve it by adding the following lines to the CMakeLists.txt:
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)

Comment: `-static` shouldn't have any effect here, if you're picking the correct libraries and it will only work for the first library following the flag (so you'd have to repeat it). Feel free to repost that comment as an answer in case someone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying the CMakeLists.txt in the following way, the created .exe worked without any errors.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(Test2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static -static-libgcc")
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)

add_executable(Test2 main.cpp)

set(SFML_ROOT "C:/Program Files/SFML-2.4.2")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_modules")
find_package(SFML 2 REQUIRED graphics network audio window system)

if(SFML_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
endif()
```